# Java Mail Api, delete mails from gmail

Tags: jakarta-mail, gmail-imap

For testing reasons, I want an email account to be empty every day, I have this code but isn't deleting the emails.

```
public class EmailService {

  private String HOST = "imap.gmail.com";
  private String USERNAME = "mail@gmail.com";
  private String PASSWORD = "pass";
  private Properties properties;
  private Store store;
  private Folder inbox;

  public EmailService() throws MessagingException {
    this.properties = new Properties();
    this.properties.put("mail.imap.host", HOST);
    this.properties.put("mail.imap.port", "993");
    this.properties.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
  }

  public void openEmailSession() throws MessagingException, InterruptedException {
    Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(this.properties);
    emailSession.setDebug(true);
    this.store = emailSession.getStore("imaps");
    this.store.connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    this.inbox = this.store.getFolder("INBOX");
    this.inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
  }

  public void closeEmailSession() throws MessagingException, IOException {
    this.inbox.close(true);
    this.store.close();
  }

  public Message[] getUserMessages() throws MessagingException, IOException {
    Message[] messages = this.inbox.getMessages();
    return messages;
  }

  public void cleanInbox() throws IOException, MessagingException {
    Message[] messages = this.getUserMessages();
    for (Message message :messages) {
      message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
    }
  }
}
```

When I execute:

```
emailService.openEmailSession();
emailService.cleanInbox();
emailService.closeEmailSession();
```

The emails disappear from inbox, but then I click on All Mail and the emails still there and the trash is empty. I don't understand what is happening.

On the gmail settings in "Forwarding and POP/IMAP" I already tried autoexpunge on/off and the three options in "When a message is marked as deleted and expunged from the last visible IMAP folder"

But nothing changes... What I'm missing?

Edit: Debug output for [Gmail]/All mail

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.6
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "imap.gmail.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK Gimap ready for requests from 46.25.184.193 f20mb151859057edc
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN AUTH=OAUTHBEARER AUTH=XOAUTH
A0 OK Thats all she wrote! f20mb151859057edc
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: OAUTHBEARER
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=imap.gmail.com, user=mail@gmail.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 OK mail@gmail.com authenticated (Success)
A2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LITERAL- APPENDLIMIT=35651584
A2 OK Success
DEBUG IMAPS: connection available -- size: 1
A3 SELECT "[Gmail]/All Mail"
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $NotPhishing $Phishing)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $NotPhishing $Phishing \*)] Flags permitted.
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 11] UIDs valid.
* 10 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UIDNEXT 3903] Predicted next UID.
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 101809]
A3 OK [READ-WRITE] [Gmail]/All Mail selected. (Success)
A4 STORE 1 +FLAGS (\Deleted)
* 1 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen \Deleted))
A4 OK Success
A5 STORE 2 +FLAGS (\Deleted)
* 2 FETCH (FLAGS (\Deleted))
A5 OK Success
A6 STORE 3 +FLAGS (\Deleted)
* 3 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen \Deleted))
A6 OK Success
A13 OK Success
A14 CLOSE
A14 OK Returned to authenticated state. (Success)
DEBUG IMAPS: added an Authenticated connection -- size: 1
A15 LOGOUT
* BYE LOGOUT Requested
A15 OK 73 good day (Success)
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPStore connection dead
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPStore cleanup, force false
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPStore cleanup done
```

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Comment: I updated the original question with debug output.

Comment: Gmail is a little "weird" when it comes to IMAP.  As I understand it, deleted messages are moved to Trash.  To really get rid of the message, you have to delete it from Trash.  If you look at "All Mail", the messages will be there because, well, it's **all mail**!  If they're not disappearing from INBOX after you delete them, that's a bigger problem.

Comment: No, no. The mails are disappearing from inbox but aren't in trash. They hasn't a label. I will try with pop3. If I delete the mails manually, then they aren't in "All mail"

Comment: Interesting.  Gmail really is pretty weird.  Can you just read and delete the messages from the All Mail folder?

Comment: No, I can't get the messages from "All Mail" (javamail api say that folder doesn't exist)

Also, try with pop3. Same result... It's really weird.

Comment: What name did you use?  The correct name is "[Gmail]/All Mail".

Comment: I tried with different variants, and right now with that. Found de folder, but not delete the mails.

Comment: Details?  What exactly did you do?  What does the JavaMail debug output show?

Comment: I get "All Mail":    << this.inbox = this.store.getFolder("[Gmail]/All Mail"); >>
I can read the emails, and mark as deleted, but when close the session, nothing happens. However, I found an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative solution, is not the best for my purpose (jenkins integration) but it works for now.

Is a really simple function in google script, you can select your email and schedule the function as you want.

https://www.google.com/script/start/

```
function cleanInbox() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:inbox');
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i].moveToTrash();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to first copy the message to the folder `[Gmail]/Trash`, which will cause it to be immediately expunged from the current folder.  Then you have to open `[Gmail]/Trash` and delete the message.  That will make the message go away for good.

I added this information to the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmaildelete).